# Compiling SharpDX : xaudio2.h(65,68): Process error CX0001: cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

i try to compile the old [SharpDX](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX) library using windows 10 64 but, visual studio 2019
but when I'm loading SharpDX.sln and hit compile in x64 debug mode I'm getting :
any idea why?

i try to compile the old [SharpDX](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX) library using windows 10 64 but, visual studio 2019
but when I'm loading SharpDX.sln and hit compile in x64 debug mode I'm getting :
any idea why?

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: SharpDX, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The operation failed as details for project SharpDX could not be loaded.
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.build.tasks.git\1.0.0-beta2-18618-05\build\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets(36,5): warning : Submodule 'Samples' doesn't have any commit, the source code won't be available via source link.
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/SharpGen-MSBuild.h:47:
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/sharpdx-xaudio2.h:2:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xaudio2.h(65,68): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:     EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY IID_IXAudio2Extension = __uuidof(IXAudio2Extension);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                                    ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xaudio2.h(71,59): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:     EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY IID_IXAudio2 = __uuidof(IXAudio2);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                           ^
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/SharpGen-MSBuild.h:47:
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/sharpdx-xaudio2.h:3:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xaudio2fx.h(31,65): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY CLSID_AudioVolumeMeter = __uuidof(AudioVolumeMeter);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                                 ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xaudio2fx.h(34,60): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY CLSID_AudioReverb = __uuidof(AudioReverb);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                            ^
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/SharpGen-MSBuild.h:48:
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/sharpdx-x3daudio.h:2:
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\x3daudio.h:62:
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\DirectXMath.h:111:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\intrin.h(56,1): Process error CX0001:  expected function body after function declarator
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: __MACHINE(void * _AddressOfReturnAddress(void))
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: ^
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/SharpGen-MSBuild.h:49:
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/sharpdx-xapo.h:3:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xapo.h(105,52): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY IID_IXAPO = __uuidof(IXAPO);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                    ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xapo.h(108,62): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY IID_IXAPOParameters = __uuidof(IXAPOParameters);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                              ^
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/SharpGen-MSBuild.h:49:
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: In file included from C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/sharpdx-xapo.h:7:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xapofx.h(34,53): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY CLSID_FXEQ = __uuidof(FXEQ);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                     ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xapofx.h(37,67): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY CLSID_FXMasteringLimiter = __uuidof(FXMasteringLimiter);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                                   ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xapofx.h(40,57): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY CLSID_FXReverb = __uuidof(FXReverb);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                         ^
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um\xapofx.h(43,55): Process error CX0001:  cannot call operator __uuidof on a type with no GUID
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: EXTERN_C const GUID DECLSPEC_SELECTANY CLSID_FXEcho = __uuidof(FXEcho);
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002:                                                       ^
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process warning CX0002: 11 errors generated.
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process error CX0003: Failed to run CastXML. Check previous errors.
1>C:\Users\foo\.nuget\packages\sharpgentools.sdk\1.1.3-ci489\build\SharpGenTools.Sdk.targets(174,5): Process error CX0003: Unable to generate XML file with castxml [C:\Dev\my\csharp\SharpDX\Source\SharpDX/obj\Debug\net40\SharpGen/SharpGen-MSBuild.xml]. Check previous errors.
1>Done building project "SharpDX.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Could you solve your problem?